# My core Comment module is gone

Tags: comments

Recently I lost comments and everything related. In the module list I see "Comment (missing)". All I did before:

- CK editor update
- Installed the [Better Formats](https://drupal.org/project/better_formats) module.

Manual updating the core from 7.27 to 7.28 didn't help. All comment module files are in the folder they suppose to be (modules/comment/). But Drupal doesn't see the module.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 1) Roll back the last backup you did prior to the changes you mention.  2) Disable Better Formats.

Comment: Thnks for the responds. Unfrtntly I can not roll back... I can but it's the lastest thing I want to do because of my own stupidness (I didn't make any backup just before those changes. the closest backup is almost 1 working day). my fault I know.

Comment: Better Formats is already even uninstalled. No changes.

Answer (score 3):

If the comment module files are there in `/modules/comment` but not displayed in Admin > Modules it suggests the folder isn't readable by the webserver user.

Check the permissions are correct on the `/modules/comment` folder to allow read access.

For example:

```
# Run from Drupal root
# Comment module folder ensure readable
chmod 755 modules/comment
# Recursive chmod on files to ensure readable
find modules/comment -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: You can also do a recursive chmod using the -R option. My personal favorite is `chmod -Rvc 755 some/directory`. It will do a chmod on the directory and everything below it and will tell you which files were changed.

Comment: @marcvangend yes, but the problem with `chmod -R 755` is it will change all _file_ permissions to 755 also. Normally 644 is more appropriate for files, with folders at 755. The `find` command with `-type f` will match files only `-type d` will match directories only.

Comment: @DavidThomas, Just checked: modules/comment has 755 rights :-(

Comment: @Andrey check permissions on files inside that folder also.

Comment: @DavidThomas I did. The are 644

Comment: Ok, must be something else going on there specific to your site configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you're unable to rollback your site to the state it was just prior to the last install/update, and its not a permissions problem, my suggestion is to migrate the content into a fresh install.

First check that the comments are not missing from the database: Use *phpMyAdmin* or another database examination tool to check the table `comment` still exists and has usable content). I'll be very surprised if it is gone if you have not actively un-installed the comment module.

Provided comments still are present, do the following:

1. Disable any module you don't need.  Disabling a module will not make you lose any data.
2. Uninstall any module that you don't absolutely need.  Un-installing  *will often cause data loss*, so carefully review your options here.
3. After  doing the above, make a full backup of your site using the [Backup and Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module.
4. Do a fresh install of the latest version Drupal core on a staging server.
5. Roll back the backup created in step 3 above into the fresh install on the staging server (do not touch your production server at this point).
6. Check that the core **Comment** module is present, enabled, and that comments appear as they're supposed to.
7. Carefully re-enable all the other modules on you want to use, one by one. Make sure you do this on the staging server.  After each install and configuration, check carefully that all is still fine.  Hopefully, this should not cause any breakage, and it should give you a healthy site at the end of the task.  If one install breaks something, you at least knows the cause, and can redo the procedure from step 4, skipping the install that causes the problem.
8. After you've restored your site to full health on a staging server, take a full backup of that, and then repeat the successful procedure on the *production server*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx. Sure that's the way I was thinking about. Hope to find an easier way before perform that one.  Anyway comments are still in the db, and I definitely did not un-install Comment module by my own. Maybe there is any  way to manually re-install that module?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem was in the traces of my old experiments: there was a folder `sites/all/modules/my_comments` with almost empty `comment.module` file inside. I have no idea why didn't that thing come up earlier (I was playing with 'module customization' a while ago and cache has been cleared many times) but now my comments are back.

Thanks everybody who where trying to help. And my apologies for my English.